# How to backup databases from Linode servers

Tags: mysql, drupal, ssh, drupal-7, linode

All they gave me is SSH login and I'm quite new to this. My site is running on Drupal 7 and in settings.php the database connect line looks like this:

```
$db_url = 'mysqli://user:pw@host:3306/dbname';
```

So it means it is using different host IP address than the SSH/SFTP, so I tried something like this:

```
mysqldump -u user -p -h host:3306 --opt dbname > backup.sql
```

But it doesn't work, I get erorrs:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'host:3306' (0) when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough:

> mysqldump -u user -p -h db_host db_name > backup.sql

Comment: No, like I wrote, you connect to SSH via sftp address, but the database is in another address. So that cmd just gives error that it cannot connect or find db.

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that part. Did you actually replace `host` with the IP address of the host you're connecting to? You can also drop the port 3306 part since that's the default MySQL port anyway.

Comment: I did, i'm just using 'host' as an example here.

Comment: Can we assume that when you removed the port part, that the back-up worked?